# Navbar hide on scroll with offset

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this code to make my sticky navbar disappear on scroll down and re-appear on scroll up. However this code is pretty precise resulting sometimes in starting one of both animations without actually scrolling.

What I'm trying to achieve is that a user should scroll 20px down before the if statement runs. Same if they would scroll up again...

https://jsfiddle.net/as1tpbjw/2/

```
const body = document.querySelector("#navbar");;
let lastScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if (currentScroll <= 0) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
        return;
    }

    if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
        body.classList.add("scroll-down");
    } else if (
        currentScroll < lastScroll &&
        body.classList.contains("scroll-down")
    ) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
        body.classList.add("scroll-up");
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

Comment: Hey. Please provide a working code snippet. I have no idea what those classes do.

Comment: I think you're looking for a way to measure the scroll "distance" before actually executing your code. `var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop` this might be helpful with that.
Taken from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/detect-user-scroll-amount.shtml

Comment: @LGT here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as1tpbjw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, in my relatively old version of Firefox, it works well.

I added `if (Math.abs(currentScroll - lastScroll) < 20) { return; }` and this adds a 20px delay either way.

Also, that `scroll-up` class doesn't seem to be doing anything in the fiddle.

Update:

If you want an animation, you can replace the CSS for `.scroll-down` and add a `transition` to `#navbar`:

```
#navbar.scroll-down {
  height: 0;
}

#navbar {
  /* … */
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

Not only does `scroll-up` do nothing, but the following code even breaks (doesn't show the navbar) when you scroll to the top:

```
if (currentScroll <= 0) {
  body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
  return;
}
```

You may want to remove it.

```js
const body = document.querySelector("#navbar");
let lastScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if (Math.abs(currentScroll - lastScroll) < 20) {
    return;
  }

  if (currentScroll > lastScroll) {
    body.classList.add("scroll-down");
  } else {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
  }

  lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 200vh;
}

#navbar.scroll-down {
  height: 0;
}

#navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! For now it doesn't seem to be working at all for me... Could you maybe share the jsfiddle? I removed the scroll-up class thanks:)

Comment: Done. Good luck. :)